# how to access client's web cam through web app

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any methods or library for asp.net/c# that allows users to take picture and record video through their web cam and then directly upload to server via web app?

Comment: Searching for tools/library is offtopic. But following searchs terms will get you started [javascript html actionscript camera record](http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+html+actionscript+camera+record) on using Flash to capture video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For taking pictures, You can access a user's webcam through some HTML5 APIs:

http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas

You'd then have to upload the images you capture to your webserver.  I'm sure a format such as mjpg would be really useful for this (From my limited experience with it, it's literally a header that specifies chunked encoding, followed by a stream of jpg files).  HTML5 also exposes functionality for capturing audio from a microphone.  I'm not sure if there is any API to merge video and audio streams into an H264 stream.